# Laravel 5 leftJoin on belongsTo relation

Tags: php, laravel

I have two database tables: users and students. A student is a user, but has extra data (address). I have a belongsTo('User') relationship in my Student model.

If I now query the Student model like this:

```
$this->student
    ->with('user')
    ->first();
```

I get this result:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 12,
    "street": "Petershof",
    "house_number": "3787",
    "postal_code": "8161 NM",
    "city": "Tienhoven",
    "user": {
        "id": 12,
        "email": "bvierdag@yahoo.nl",
        "first_name": "Nathan",
        "last_name": "van Dijk",
        "name": "Nathan van Dijk"
    }
}
```

However, I want to flatten the result, so that the user fields are in the parent (Student) object. Like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 12,
    "street": "Petershof",
    "house_number": "3787",
    "postal_code": "8161 NM",
    "city": "Tienhoven",
    "email": "bvierdag@yahoo.nl",  // = user field
    "first_name": "Nathan",        // = user field
    "last_name": "van Dijk",       // = user field
    "name": "Nathan van Dijk"      // = user field
}
```

I have tried to use leftJoin('users', 'user_id', '=', 'users.id') instead of with(), but then I lose my virtual attribute 'name' (defined in the User model) and also can't query relations of User anymore.

How can I achieve this in a clean way?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->student
  ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'students.user_id')
  ->select(
    'students.*',
    'users.email',
    'users.first_name',
    'users.last_name',
    DB::raw("concat(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) as name"),
  )->first();
```

You could drop the table in select like `users.email` in this case.

The relations will work just the same, I suppose the problem was only with overriding `students` id with `users` id, if you didn't specify the `select` and just grabbed all the fields.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is a good way to go for now, but the thing I don't really like is that you skip the User model. So if I want to change the virtual name field, I have to change it on different locations.

Comment: What do you mean by *skip user model* ? If the only thing you want to achieve is output presentation, in form of JSON I suppose, then you should have said that.

Comment: I mean that with using leftJoin() I have to rewrite the 'virtual name field' as an sql concat, while I already defined it in the User model, so that is double code and not DRY. Ideally would be to do something like this: $this->student->with(user, 'left join')->first(). Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't worry about DRY in such case. You either use Eloquent with all its features (ie. no `joins` on relations at all) or you use custom queries (like I've shown above). So, no, there's no way to achieve that. And, again, tell me what you want it for, then I can suggest the solution.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your explanation. I want to create a JSON api. There are more complex relationships to come, so what would be your advice? Use Eloquent, custom sql, or maybe other ORM?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but here goes.

Reading your comment it seems you want to make an api for this. If it's only one endpoint formatting the result on the fly shouldn't be an issue however for more endpoints I would suggest a transformer pattern.

This would work by having a separate class return an array based on your db data. Then you take that array and use it in your `response()`.

So, in your controller, instead of doing something like `return response(Student::all());` you could do something like `return response(StudentTransformer::transform(Student::all()))`.

The advantage here is you have only one folder (your `Transformers`) to check for response data format. The disadvantage is when your DB changes you also need to update your transformers.